# Graphing series with different X values

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to graph a series of data sets which all have different x values with Google Charts. It seems however that all the line and scatter charts only support 1 x values for all series.

The data sets I have are basically csv strings like these:

```
Set1:
x1, x2, x3, x4
y1, y2, y3, y4

Set2:
x5, x6, x7, x8
y5, y6, y7, y8
```

The x's may be the same in each series, or they may differ.

I would prefer to just be able to throw the x and y values into the chart instead of going through all the data to find the x values and then make sure each set has the same x values.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can use the same 'X' value multiple times.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Set 1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Set 2');
data.addRows([
  [x1, y1, null],
  [x2, y2, null],
  [x3, y3, null],
  [x4, y4, null],
  [x5, null, y5],
  [x6, null, y6],
  [x7, null, y7],
  [x8, null, y8],
]);
```

Alternatively, you can make them all part of the same series (if you want one color). So long as you aren't connecting them with lines, you won't be able to tell the difference. You can have the same X value a dozen times if you'd like, with separate points for Y for each one.

I would write a function to turn your CSV values in to a format like the above.

Comment: There are other ways (such as performing a join on the two tables) which may be easier depending on how you get your data/how you want the chart to work.